# Can't use variable name GET in Twig macro

Tags: php, twig

If I use variable 'GET' in a Twig macro, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _GET in /var/www/basedir/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(331) : eval()'d code on line 21
```

After scratching my head, I found I could change the name from 'GET' to 'get', and the error goes away.  It is okay, however, to use variable `GET` in the template, just not the macro.

I could and will change the name.  My question is why is this happening, and are there other non-allowed variable names which I must be aware of?

```
<?php
require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
try {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true,));
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
    echo $twig->render('get.html', array('GET'=>$_GET));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

get.html

```
{% import "forms.html" as forms %}

{{ forms.someFunction(GET) }}
```

forms.html

```
{% macro someFunction(GET) %}
{{ dump(GET) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: is twig maybe using internally underscores and then tries to write `$_GET = ...` which fails? Just not use it, I'd say.

Comment: @bwoebi.  Maybe.  I found variable name `POST` and `SESSION` causes similar issues, however, variable `XXX` is okay.  I guess one must stay away from all PHP global variables.  Don't think this is documented anywhere.

Comment: then report that to twig, Stackoverflow seems to be the wrong place for that...

Comment: @Didn't know at first what was going on.  Done: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/1511